# A chart in the tooltip is not being fully rendered

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I generate a tooltip with a chart on it.

```
tooltip: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    enabled: true,
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    useHTML: true,
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        Highcharts.chart(div, {
            chart: {
                height: 300,
                width: 300
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Title'
            },
            series: [
                {
                    data: [10, 20],
                    color: 'red'
                },
                {
                    data: [20, 10],
                    color: 'green'
                }
            ],
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Quantity'
                }
            }
        });

        return div.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

### Real data example

The main chart is of the `line` type. The tooltip chart is of the `column` type.

[image]

### Dummy data example

The main chart is of the `line` type. The tooltip chart is of the `line` type as well. You may see half-visible red and green symbols. They are either hidden by *something* (I am trying to figure out what it is) or were suddenly stopped being rendered (I highly doubt it).

[image]

Do you have any ideas what it could be?

### Update 1

I was able to identify the element the series are rendered into. It's there, the size seems correct, it has points rendered.

```
 <g class="highcharts-series-group" data-z-index="3">...</g>
```

Though, I couldn't bring it to the front, or make it visible by any CSS means.

[image]

That's basically the question. How to bring it to the forward or unhide?

### Update 2

I was experimenting with setting the dimensions by both

```
div.style.width = "500px";
```

and

```
chart: {
    height: 300,
    width: 300
}
```

to no avail.

### Update 3

[I created a jsfiddle. Please, have a look.](https://jsfiddle.net/tobilko/6yxmz59s/)

Do you have any ideas? Any thought would be invaluable.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel please, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/tobilko/6yxmz59s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this issue is quite simple. In the formatter callback function you are returning an innerHTML of a div with a created chart. However, this is not the interactive chart but only HTML.

The chart plot area is hidden because of the animation. Disable it and you will see plotted series:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    animation: false
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/us4dvgy9/

---

Another solution is to return an HTML div element in the tooltip formatter and then create a chart inside the div using setTimeout. With this approach the animation is working fine.

**Code:**

```
formatter: function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    Highcharts.chart('tooltip', {
      chart: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Title'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        data: [50, 75],
        color: 'red',
        selected: true
      }, {
        data: [10, 100],
        color: 'green'
      }],
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Quantity'
        }
      }
    });
  }, 0);

  return '<div id="tooltip"></div>';
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rh6pw5s2/